# Discord bot only responding to a message once

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm hoping this will have a simple solution i'm just unfamiliar with. I have a Discord bot and have got it working pretty well to set up a series of tasks. I've been using this and it works great:

```
if message.content.startswith('hi'):
    await message.channel.send('hello')
```

So this works great and all but you can keep spamming 'hi' and bot will always respond 'hello'. Is there some code or instruction so that bot will only ever do this once?

Comment: You need to set some kind of flag when reponding and check whether that flag was set before reponding. What that flag looks like technically depends on what "ever" means to you. Could be a variable, could be a file entry.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere on how to set flags?

Comment: The comment explains what he means by "flags", either a variable or a file, you can also use a database. There are some good tutorials online on working with files, like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)

Comment: A "flag" is just a basic programming term. It describes any method to memorize some small piece of information that you know you'll need again later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of a flag as a variable:

```py
saidhi = False#Place this at the start of your code and whenever you want to reset the system
if message.content.startswith("hi"):
    global saidhi #Referencing the global variable saidhi, to enable changing it
    if not saidhi:
        saidhi = True
        await message.channel.send("hello")
```

Comment: thanks for providing, I was working along the lines of something like this. I find this doesn't seem to work though? It seems to always be stuck on either False or True. They work on their own (like if I set saidhi = True then booted it up then it won't send), they just don't seem to ever change.

Comment: i've edited my answer to something that works properly

Comment: I tried using the edited version, now it states: "SyntaxError: name 'saidhi' is assigned to before global declaration"

Comment: I'm guessing I need to globally declare it, is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: never mind, I figured out what I did wrong. Thank you so much, your code works great!